# CORS error even with cors nom package installed

Tags: node.js, reactjs, filepond

I am using [React Filepond](https://github.com/pqina/react-filepond) and the uploading part is working fine. But when I go to an existing record and try to display the image, I get a CORS error:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8000/img/myImg.jpg'
>   from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy:
>   No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource.

in app.js on my node server I have the below but I still get the cors error using the [cors package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors)

```
const cors = require("cors");
app.use(cors());
app.options("*", cors());
```

In React I have the following:

```
  state = {
    data: {
      title: "",
      bgImg: ""
    },
    errors: {},
    files: [
      {
        source: "myImg.jpg",

        options: {
          type: "local"
        }
      }
    ]
  };

    <FilePond
      ref={ref => (this.pond = ref)}
      files={this.state.files}
      allowMultiple={false}
      maxFiles={1}
      name="bgImg"
      server={{
        process: "http://localhost:8000/api/uploads/",
        load: "http://localhost:8000/img/"
      }}
      oninit={() => this.handleInit()}
      onupdatefiles={fileItems => {
        this.setState({
          files: fileItems.map(fileItem => fileItem.file)
        });
      }}
    />
```

In package.json I have also added a proxy:

```
"proxy": "http://localhost:8000/img",
```

Network tab -> headers tab shows

```
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/img/myImg.jpg
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade

Provisional headers are shown
Referer: http://localhost:3000/home-banner
```

Comment: Test if the response in the developer tools network tab actually shows the required CORS headers.

Comment: @Rik, not sure if I am looking in the right place but I have updated my original question with what shows up.

Comment: https://ibb.co/LnZ6pf9 the access-control headers are what you need.

Comment: Is the CORS package on the node.js server not catering for that or do I need to also install that on the React project?

Comment: I don't know, I don't have a lot of experience with NodeJS, I do know this is something that is configured on the server not the client.

Comment: I will deploy this to see if I have the same issue on a live server as it's running on localhost at the moment and let you know...

Comment: @Rik, I am not sure if this is a suitable solution but I had to use cors anywhere to get it to work, it's the only thing that actually works for me. https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com

Answer (score 0):

Try installing cors plugin in your browser and access the api. Hope this helps..

```
const cors = require('cors')

const corsOptions = {
  origin: 'http://localhost:8000'
}

app.get('/img', cors(corsOptions), (req, res, next) => {
  //...
})
```